# ffmpeg dump attachements to subfolder

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I was looking for a method to extract all attachments(fonts) from a .mkv file.

I found the following command in the manual:

```
ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t "" -i myfile.mkv
```

however this extracts the attachments to same folder, I need to save the attachments in a sub-folder.

How do I achieve this?

I need it because I'm going to use this command inside  a for loop, and each file's attachments must be extracted to a different folder

Thanks in advance

Comment: Inside the for loop, move the attachments from PWD to target directory.

Comment: It might be feasible by copying all .ttf / .otf... But I prefer to keep the original directory clean, if it's possible...

Comment: Then, at each iteration, cd to the target dir first, and run ffmpeg with full path to the input

Comment: In fact... that... solved my problem. Thanks @Gyan :) I'm still curious to know if there's a way to specify an output folder with ffmpeg dump_attachment or not.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be a full path with filename.